# EF 4.3 One To Many Relationship With Minimal Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Which should match to a schema in the database which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts]
(
    [ContactId]         NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]         NVARCHAR(150)   NOT NULL,
    [LastName]          NVARCHAR(150)   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhoneNumbers]
(
    [PhoneNumberId]     INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    [ContactId]         NVARCHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]       NVARCHAR(20)        NOT NULL,
    [Type]              NVARCHAR(1000)      NOT NULL
)
```

And I have two class which implement EntityTypeConfiguration as well.

```
public class PhoneNumberConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PhoneNumber>
{
    public PhoneNumberConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable(TableName);

        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberId");
        Property(e => e.Value).HasColumnName("PhoneNumber");
        Property(e => e.PhoneType).HasColumnName("Type");
    }
}

public class ContactConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public ContactConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Contacts");

        Property(contact => contact.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ContactId");
    }
}
```

From this, can I use EF 4.3's fluent API to specify that the foreign key between the phone number and persons is in the phone number table stored in a field called ContactId?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In the `ContactConfiguration` constructor add the mapping:

```
HasMany(contact => contact.PhoneNumbers)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(map => map.MapKey("ContactId"));
```